# computation of the number of characters in a lenghty string

Tags: c

In the function I got, I receive in arguments, a string which can contain, in theory, an infinite number of characters (but let say it's really long).
I need to scan this string to know its exact length. Normally I would use

```
int i = 0;
while (str[i] != '\0') {
   i++;
}
```

But, if we consider that the string is really long like it has 1 trillion characters, it means that at the end of the scan, "i" takes the value 1 trillion. 
Indeed, it's way too much for an integer. Though, don't tell me to use a long cause I could also say that i = 10^1000000000...

So, is there a technique or a function (hand-made) i could use/make to solve this problem or is it simply impossible?
If so, it'd have to re-think my algorithm and ask another question but i believe the problem would be the same in the end.

As always, i can only use write, malloc, free and cannot use other functions/commands. Everything else needs to be hand-made.

Comment: use string function strlen(). Its returns the length of the string passed

Comment: Normally one would use `strlen` for this.  It returns a `size_t`, which is an integer type large enough to hold the length of any string.  You could write your own version that uses `size_t` as the type of its counter, but there's not much reason to do so.

Comment: Are you essentially asking for a datatype that can store theoretically infinitely large numbers?

Comment: How do you intend to store a string with 10^1000000000 characters in memory? People who designed your language/system are not idiots, they know that sometimes objects can be quite large therefore the data type to store the size of things in memory, `size_t` is big enough to express the largest size of an object that the memory can store. Just use strlen.

Comment: If by "_Everything else needs to be hand-made_" you mean you're on some _really_ weird embedded system or something that _doesn't_ have some reasonable subset of the standard library (but _does_ have enough memory for stupidly large strings), then you should explicitly say so in the question, otherwise everyone will just tell you to use `strlen()`.

Comment: So you are being cautious because you have a way of storing 9 quintillion bytes? And what does the sentence *"As always, i can only use write, malloc, free and cannot use other functions/commands"* mean? Do your clients pay you to rewrite standard library functions? Isn't it better to save time and use code that has been written by professionals and tested for years in production?

Comment: When i said that i couldn't use any function exept for write, malloc and free, i ment that strlen, strcmp, strcpy and any other function isn't allowed, i didn't choose it, that's just how i'm supposed to do my programm. The few lines of program i wrote earlier is a function name my_strlen which is an hand-made version of strlen. Thing is, int is limited so this function is obsolete. Also, and to answer Steve, i need a solution, a tip to solve my problem of computing the size of this string whatever size it has

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason at all to hand-code a loop doing nothing but finding the length of a string. C already has a standard library function for that: [`strlen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen). You should trust your standard C library that this function uses the best approach possible to scan the string.

The return value uses the type `size_t` for a reason: `size_t` is **guaranteed** to be able to hold **any** size an object (in memory) can ever have on your machine. If the length of a string doesn't fit in `size_t`, the string itself doesn't fit in the address-space of your machine in the first place.

That said, better get used to use `size_t` everywhere you handle sizes of objects and indices into arrays. You'll never have to worry about overflows that way, no matter how large your objects get.

Comment: Not to mention, counting the number of characters using ++ will work as (mod 0xFFFFFFFF)(assuming size of int is 4 bytes)

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD no, that would be the case with `unsigned int`. Overflow of a *signed* type is just *undefined*, although many implementations wrap around.

Comment: When i said that i couldn't use any function exept for write, malloc and free, i ment that strlen, strcmp, strcpy and any other function isn't allowed, i didn't choose it, that's just how i'm supposed to do my programm. The few lines of program i wrote earlier is a function name my_strlen which is an hand-made version of strlen. Thing is, int is limited so this function is obsolete.

Comment: So? Can't you make **this little mental step** to use `size_t` yourself in your own reinvention of `strlen()`?

Comment: Make sure when you write your custom function that u detect an overflow. Theoretically, its impossible to store infinite size string due to memory constraints

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD didn't you understand my answer? There's nothing "theoretically" impossible, a `size_t` can store **any possible** size. No overflows to detect.

Answer (score 0):

The function Strlen() in the standard library does this for you. Every thing you are trying to do with your while loop has already been done before. Save yourself the trouble of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: When i said that i couldn't use any function exept for write, malloc and free, i ment that strlen, strcmp, strcpy and any other function isn't allowed, i didn't choose it, that's just how i'm supposed to do my programm. The few lines of program i wrote earlier is a function name my_strlen which is an hand-made version of strlen. Thing is, int is limited so this function is obsolete.

Comment: You might choose to declare it as the largest type your system can hold. As @Felix said if it exceeds that, it won't fit in the address space of your computer in the first place. But I don't think size_t which is unsigned int is the largest unless your system is a 32 bit one. If it is a 64 bit system, unsigned long might be the way to go.

Comment: I'm on a 64 bit architecture.  `size_t` is defined as `unsigned long`